# desired horizontal alignment of pgfplots' axis in tikzpicture environment inside tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

this is the first time I ask a question on this site (benefited from a lot of answer, though). I have problems with horizontal alignment of pgfplots' `axis` inside a `tabular` environment.
**My target, independend from specific following examples, is to get a matrix of 3x2 square axis which fill up exactly the textwidth cnsidering or not considering the ylabels/yticklabels.**
In the following MWE, two `tikzpicture`s are loaded by respective files containing them. The long `caption` of the `figure` and the red boxes evidences how the alignment is poor. I wonder why..
In addition I think that `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` aren't working properly, as well. In this sense I would like to know how to tightly fill the `\textwidth` both with and without considering labels and ticklabels

[image: this is what I get. Black hand-drawn lines are meant to evidence how the alignment is not considering nor ignoring the ticklabels]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage[font=small, format=hang, labelfont={sf,bf}, tableposition=top, figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\newcommand{\mat}{\mathbf}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{lr}
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{pippo1}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/lele_w.tikz}
      &
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{pipo2}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/lele_distorsion.tikz}
      \\
   \end{tabular}%
   \caption{\textsl{Left}: Plot of the real part of the modified wavenumber, $w'_\text{r}$, vs. wavenumber $w$ for first derivative approximations: (a) \nth{2} order explicit; (b) \nth{4} order explicit; (d) \nth{4} order tridiagonal (Padé); (e) \nth{6} order tridiagonal; (f) \nth{8} order tridiagonal; (h) \nth{10} order pentadiagonal.\\ \textsl{Right}: $w$-$w'$ plane stretched orthogonally to the bisector by a factor 500; each grey line results from the overlapping --- to eye precision --- of one horizontal and one vertical grid line on the \textsl{left}, due to the heavy distortion.}
    \label{fig:pippo}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The file lele_w.tikz sould contain

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]

   \begin{axis}[grid=major,axis equal image=true,xmin=0,xmax=pi,xtick={0,.7854,...,3.1416},xticklabels={{},$\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{4}$,{}},x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east},xlabel={$w$},ymin=0,ymax=pi,ytick={0,.7854,...,3.1416},yticklabels={{},$\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{4}$,{}},y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north east,rotate=-90},ylabel={$\Re(w')$}]
      % exact
      \addplot[mark=none] {x};
   \end{axis}

   \draw[red]
(current axis.below south west)
rectangle (current axis.above north east);
   \draw[red]
(current axis.left of south west)
rectangle (current axis.right of north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

whereas lele_distorsion.tikz sould contain

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis right]

   \begin{axis}[ylabel={$\Re(w')$},yticklabel pos=right,%at={(main axis.right of south east)},
   %xshift=7cm,%anchor=south west,
   axis equal image=true,xmin=0,xmax=pi,ymin=0,ymax=pi,ticks=none]

      % exact
      \addplot[mark=none] {x};

   \end{axis}

   \draw[red]
(current axis.below south west)
rectangle (current axis.above north east);
   \draw[red]
(current axis.left of south west)
rectangle (current axis.right of north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have done as @Harish Kumar said, but it don't works entirely to me.
I add the code a different figure with a set of 3x2 axis environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage[font=small, format=hang, labelfont={sf,bf}, tableposition=top, figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{lr}
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{re1}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/re1.tikz}
      &
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{im1}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/im1.tikz}
      \\
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{re2}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/re2.tikz}
      &
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{im2}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/im2.tikz}
      \\
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{re3}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/re3.tikz}
      &
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{im3}
      \includegraphics{immagini/tikz/wpvsw/im3.tikz}
      \\
   \end{tabular}%
   \caption{\textsl{Left}: Plot of the real part of the modified wavenumber, $w'_\text{r}$, vs. wavenumber $w$ for first derivative approximations: (a) \nth{2} order explicit; (b) \nth{4} order explicit.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the upper left file is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=.75,fill=white}}
   \pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={
               /pgf/number format/precision=1,
               /pgf/number format/fixed,
               /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
               }}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={line width=.25pt}}

    \begin{axis}[width=.5\textwidth,height=.5\textwidth,
      ylabel={$\text{Re}\left(k'\right)$},
        xmin=0,xmax=pi,ymin=0,ymax=pi,axis equal image=true,
        xtick={.5,1,...,3},
      xticklabels={},
        ytick={.5,1,...,3},
        grid=major,trim axis left]
      \addplot[mark=none] {x};
   \end{axis}       

   \draw[red]
(current axis.below south west)
rectangle (current axis.above north east);
   \draw[red]
(current axis.left of south west)
rectangle (current axis.right of north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

the upper right file is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=.75,fill=white}}
   \pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={
               /pgf/number format/precision=1,
               /pgf/number format/fixed,
               /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
               }}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={line width=.25pt}}

   \begin{axis}[width=.5\textwidth,height=.5\textwidth,
      ylabel={$\text{Im}\left(k'\right)$},
        xmin=0,xmax=pi,ymin=-2e-2,ymax=1.6e-1,
        xtick={.5,1,...,3},
      xticklabels={},
        ytick={0,2e-2,4e-2,6e-2,8e-2,10e-2,12e-2,14e-2,16e-2},
        scaled y ticks={base 10:2},tick scale binop=\times,
      yticklabel pos=right,
        grid=major,trim axis right]
   \end{axis}

   \draw[red]
(current axis.below south west)
rectangle (current axis.above north east);
   \draw[red]
(current axis.left of south west)
rectangle (current axis.right of north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

the lower 2 (1x2) plots have both labels and ticklabels

The `axis`' options `width=.5\textwidth,height=.5\textwidth` serve for the plots to be all square, even if the plots on the right have different scales in x and y directions, as you can see in following picture

[image]

Comment: You should add `trim axis right/left` to the axis options, not `tikzpicture. It is better to use `width` key` and put the plots directly rather than the tabular. :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vwMYF.png

Comment: I wonder why in section 4.19.4 of the Revision 1.12.1 (2015/05/02) of the Manual for package PGFPLOTS trim axis right/left are used as trikzpicture options, not axis' options.
Anyway I tried to do so and I get the correct alignment on the left, but not on the right.

About the use of tabular, in the MWE I have included a set of only 1x2 axes to get a shorter code, but actually I need to use a set of 2x2 or even 3x2 axes.

Comment: OK that is good improvement. You should also make the `\tabcolsep` zero by `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}r@{}}`. With these and  since you use `tikzscale` why not use `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{lele_w.tikz}` and `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{lele_distorsion.tikz}`?

Comment: This is related to another problem I struggled against minutes ago. I actually assign `width=0.5\textwidth` and `height=0.5\textwidth` as options of `\begin{axis}`to get square axis even if x e y axes have different scaling, as is the case in other plots (I'd preferred to use something like MATLAB's `axis square`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With given TikZ pictures I can not reproduce your problem, but examination of your figure show, that you like that images in the first rows differ from images in second row in `xlabel` and `xticklabels`. Latter one apparently jut out of right and top border of diagram and make image slightly biger. So, I suggest you to slightly increase `xmax` from `xmax=pi` to for example `xmax=1.05*pi` as well `ymax` with the same size as `xmax` (left imeges in your figure). See code below. With this I obtain:

[image]

I generate above figure I put your TikZ images directly in figure. Include their pdf files should not change their appearance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,patterns,shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,
             width=0.5\textwidth-2*\tabcolsep, % <--- new,
             height=0.5\textwidth-2*\tabcolsep,% common for all tikz pictures
every axis plot/.append style={line width=1pt}
            }
\usepackage[font=small,
            format=hang,
            labelfont={sf,bf},
            tableposition=top,
            figureposition=bottom]{caption}

\newcommand{\mat}{\mathbf}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\[1ex]% only for show, that the images fit to width of text
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l r@{}}
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{pippo1}
%\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
               /pgf/number format/precision=1,
               /pgf/number format/fixed,
               /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
      ylabel={$\text{Re}\left(k'\right)$},
        xmin=0,xmax=pi,%<------- corrected
        ymin=0,ymax=pi,%<------- corrected
        axis equal image=true,
        xtick={.5,1,...,3},
      xticklabels={},
        ytick={.5,1,...,3},
        grid=major,trim axis left]
      \addplot[mark=none] {x};
   \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{pipo2}
%      \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

   \begin{axis}[
      ylabel={$\text{Im}\left(k'\right)$},
        xmin=0,xmax=pi,ymin=-2e-2,ymax=1.6e-1,
        xtick={.5,1,...,3},
      xticklabels={},
        ytick={0,2e-2,4e-2,6e-2,8e-2,10e-2,12e-2,14e-2,16e-2},
        scaled y ticks={base 10:2},tick scale binop=\times,
      yticklabel pos=right,
        grid=major,trim axis right]
   \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
      \\
%------------------------------------------
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{pippo1}
%\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{axis}[
      ylabel={$\text{Re}\left(k'\right)$},
        xmin=0,xmax=pi,
        ymin=0,ymax=pi,
        axis equal image=true,
        xtick={.5,1,...,3},
       xticklabels={0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0},
        ytick={.5,1,...,3},
        grid=major,trim axis left,
        xlabel={$k$}]
      \addplot[mark=none] {x};
   \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
      %\tikzsetnextfilename{pipo2}
%      \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \begin{axis}[
      ylabel={$\text{Im}\left(k'\right)$},
        xmin=0,xmax=pi,ymin=-2e-2,ymax=1.6e-1,
        xtick={.5,1,...,3},
      xticklabels={0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0},
        ytick={0,2e-2,4e-2,6e-2,8e-2,10e-2,12e-2,14e-2,16e-2},
        scaled y ticks={base 10:2},tick scale binop=\times,
      yticklabel pos=right,
        grid=major,trim axis right,
        xlabel={$k$}]
]
   \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{tabular}%
   \caption{%
\textsl{Left}: Plot of the real part of the modified wavenumber, $w'_\text{r}$, vs. wavenumber $w$ for first derivative approximations: (a) \nth{2} order explicit; (b) \nth{4} order explicit; (d) \nth{4} order tridiagonal (Padé); (e) \nth{6} order tridiagonal; (f) \nth{8} order tridiagonal; (h) \nth{10} order pentadiagonal.\\
%
\textsl{Right}: $w$-$w'$ plane stretched orthogonally to the bisector by a factor 500; each grey line results from the overlapping --- to eye precision --- of one horizontal and one vertical grid line on the \textsl{left}, due to the heavy distortion.}
    \label{fig:pippo}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I change `pdfplotsset`, it now contain all common data for all pgf plots. There I defined width of images as `0.5\\textwidth-2*\tabcolsep`, which acomodate plots to space in table cells. There I with `@{}` eliminate left and right space in table.

Now I also omit red lines around images and return maximal value of x axis to `pi`. I hope, th

Comment: I still see a misalignment on the right side, where the yticklabel exceeds the limit given by the caption. Try to remove all ylabels/yticklabels from the  axis on the right, you'll get a not-filled textwidth.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, seems that i misunderstand question. You like to have aligned right border of question and image. You just need to make your images smaller (better solution), or reduce distance between them (quick solution,). With latter I change my answer.

Comment: This is almost perfect solution, except for the change of upper x and y limits from _pi_ to _1.05*pi_. Is there a way to retain _pi_ as limit **and** to fill up the textwidth exactly? (maybe changing bounding box of images in the second row?)

Actually I'd like to understand which are the lines of your code that makes the work. I think one is `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\;}r@{}}`. But I see that if I eliminate the extra space `\;` (it's just to understand), the figure does not fill up the `\textwidth` anymore; so what's the role of `width=.5\textwidth,height=.5\textwidth` in the `axis`' options?

Comment: In other words how `.5\textwidth` of left pictures + `.5\textwidth` of right picture + `\;` = `\textwidth`?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, se recend update of my answer. I hope that npow I catch, what you like to obtain. I rewrite my MWE.

Comment: Definitely perfect!

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, I'm glad to help you. And if it is perfect, show this with vote for my answer (with click on upper pen) :-)

Comment: I've accepted it as answer, but for now I cannot vote it, since I have less then 15 reputation, sorry. I try to keep this in mind for when I'll have enough reputation